# Use the same replacement character for sqlite3 and pyscopg in Python?

Tags: python, sqlite, psycopg2

I have a painted-myself-into-a-corner question that hopefully has a sensible solution I'm overlooking. I had a Python project using sqlite3, which I like a lot and use all the time, and I wanted to try to also support running it on postgres, in case scaling becomes an issue.

Some initial research suggested that there wasn't really a single de facto Python database abstraction layer (hopefully I didn't get this wrong), but psycopg2 fortunately seemed to have very similar structure and methods to sqlite3, and I was able to get away with only adding a couple helper functions and switch cases to my existing code to allow it to support both database libraries with the same queries.

The only exception, unbelievably enough, is the replacement character for variables; sqlite3 needs `?` and psycopg2 needs `%s`. These are probably inherent to sqlite and postgres themselves for all I know.

This means that a function like this:

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO repositories (repository_url, repository_name, repository_type, repository_thumbnail, last_crawl_timestamp, item_url_pattern) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)", (repository_url, repository_name, repository_type, repository_thumbnail, time.time(), item_url_pattern))
```

Will only work for postgres, and if I change the %s's, to ?'s, it'll only work for sqlite. This defies any kind of elegant solution -- I don't really want to rig up some kind of string replacement to construct my queries, as that'll get dumb pretty quickly -- and mostly I'm just astonished that this has turned out to be my blocker.

Any thoughts?

Comment: "de facto Python database abstraction layer" — [SQLAlchemy?](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/)

Answer (score 1):

The API in use by both implementations is the Python Database API Specification v2.0, documented in [PEP 249](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/). The module global `paramstyle` tells you what style of parameters a particular implementation expects. The possible values and meanings are documented [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#paramstyle).

Comment: OK, is there any sensible way I can override paramstyle directly depending on what I've set my `dbtype` variable to, without needing to add a case block to every single query?

Comment: No, it's a constant, you can't override it. A higher level API like SQLAlchemy is a decent option if you care about easy mobility between dbs. For smaller, simpler things you can hack it, although such solutions (including most you can find online) are pretty fragile. Similarly, for relatively small things if you're converting once (sqlite to pg, no turning back), search and replace does the job.

Comment: OK, thanks! I guess I should've used SQLAlchemy in the first place, though this still feels like a dumb thing to get stuck on. Oh well.